# Is VHDL Turing complete?

Tags: programming-languages, vhdl, theory, turing-complete

Is VHDL Turing complete? My understanding is that VHDL creates a register machine, and that register machines - without arbitrary RAM - aren't Turing complete.

Is this accurate? For problems that can't be solved in register machines, is there a standard approach - use RAM outside the VHDL, and manage it via VHDL, for instance?

Comment: You can certainly implement RAM in VHDL, for a start. For synthesis, most FPGAs will map your RAM into dedicated memory blocks. It may not be the cheapest form of memory, but that's an economic argument, not a fundamental one.

Comment: VHDL has dynamic memory allocation so it is as complete as any other systems programming language.

Answer (score 7):

There are 3 main [criteria for Turing Completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_program_theorem):

1. Sequence. *do this thing and then do that thing and then do the other thing*
2. Selection. ***if** this **then** something*
3. Iteration (or recursion). *do this over and over until this*

The requirement for memory is not that it be infinite (which is impossible with modern technology, and all languages would fail), but that it be unbounded, or infinitely extendible: ie. if you run out, you can add more and try again.

So yes, I think VHDL certainly qualifies. It can do all that stuff.

Comment: Can you give a code example showing recursion in VHDL?

Comment: I found [a thread which has an example](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.vhdl/6iriCKNutv8/discussion).

Comment: @SRobertJames: A state machine can very easily exhibit recursion, and I don't think anyone is going to argue that we can't build a state machine in VHDL.

Comment: @Bill - State machines are most certainly _not_ Turing complete.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to show turing completeness is a chain of transformations:

1. Turing Machines are turing complete.
2. Turing Machines can be simulated by register machines and vice versa.
3. Register machines are an abstract and simple model of a modern processor
4. You can describe a processor with VHDL

So VHDL is turing complete.

Comment: But, can you actually simulate the layout with VHDL? I mean, suppose a JPEG photograph of a circuit can be converted into a VHDL, does this mean that JPEG Is turing complete? Being able to hold something that is turing complete, but requires an interpreter doesn't make the container turing complete.

Comment: A lithography description is just an other way how to write down a Turing Machine. When executing register and Turing Machine with pen&paper, no one requires the paper and the pen to be turing complete.

Comment: I wonder if the person doing the arithmetic is turing complete, rather than lets say the pen and paper :-)